# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout' - Trying to process multiple URLs with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to grab and parse multiple URLs using urllib and BeautifulSoup, but I get the following error:

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'**

From what I understand, the parser is telling me that I submitted a list and it is looking for a single URL. How can I process multiple URLs?

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
import urllib.request


def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True

addresses = ["https://en.wikipedia.org", "https://stackoverflow.com", "https://techcrunch.com"]

def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

html = urllib.request.urlopen(addresses).read()
print(text_from_html(html))
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error? I don't see `timeout`, so I'm not sure which line is causing the problem.

Comment: You can't `urlopen` a list of addresses, see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html

Comment: @mindfolded here it is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 21, in <module>
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(addresses).read()
  File "C:\Users\Pavel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Pavel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 516, in open
    req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Comment: thanks @RockyLi, I'll take a look at the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error clearly said `'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'`

It's because urlopen doesn't take in a list. you should nest it in a loop like this:

```
my_texts = []
for each in addresses
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(addresses).read()
    print(text_from_html(html)) # or assign to variable like:
    my_texts.append(text_from_html(html))
```

I would suggest you to use a better module for http than `urllib`, use `requests` instead (`import requests`)

Comment: What module would you recommend?